# Pasar id de ticket entre archivos no funciona

Tags: php

Despues de registrar un ticket, genero un pdf del mismo, para esto quiero pasar a otra url el id del ticket para buscar sus datos.

```html
<div class="embed-container">
    
<iframe src="/views/modules/facta/imprimeA.php?id="+<?php $_GET['id']; ?> style="width: 1000px; border: none;">
    
</iframe></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veran el id llega a contentPDF, que es el contenido del modal:

```js
                                                       
$('.modal-body').load('contentPDF.php?id='+data,function(){
        $('#myModalPDF').modal({show:true});
    });
```

Es decir el valor de data llega perfecto. Pero no me lo toma en imprimeA, lo necesito para consultar los datos del ticket.

si hago un

```
<?php    var_dump($_GET['id']); ?>
```

en contentPDF.php lo devuelve perfecto.

Comment: veo en el log de red dos entradas posteriores `imprimeA.php?id=` que al parecer no estan recibiendo el id. Puedes buscar en tu codigo donde se hace referencia a esta pagina y revisa si esta pasando un `id` correctamente.

Comment: No sabes porque llama dos veces al archivo imprimeA.php?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno estaba mal la cadena del iframe(mal concatenada):

```
<iframe src="/views/modules/facta/imprimeA.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" style="width: 1000px; border: none;">
```

Ahora funciona perfecto.